# React/Redux Why does specific component update, when its sibling’s child component updates, though its state doesn’t change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, redux-thunk

**Update**
  The sidedrawers state is apparently different, but value does not change...

[image]

**Details:** 
There is a layout component, which takes in routes from react router as children.
Inside the layout component code, two child components are rendered, Toolbar, and sidedrawer, and a main section that contains this.props.children.

One of the routes renders a component called page. Page renders another component called graphContainer, and passes it a click event, which is applied to the graphContainer’s button that it renders.

How it works is, I grab the first eight graphs and show 4 of them. When the button is clicked, it decides to either show the next 4 or grab the next eight.

This whole thing uses redux. There’s a page state, authentication state, navigation state, and a graph state. The only partial state changing when the button is clicked, is the graphs.

However, both the GraphContainer updates along with the sidedrawer component. As far as I can tell, nothing in the sidedrawer component is changing, so it should not trigger an update.

In the redux page for navigation state, the switch hits the default, which just returns state.
The graph redux portion works just fine, updates accordingly.

**My workaround** was to implement a dontUpdate prop in the navigation reducer state. And then use shouldComponentUpdate to check that prop, because the shallow check that was done by default, say with pureComponent, was seeing a different state or prop.

**tl;dr:** Any ideas why the sidedrawer component keeps updating, even though, as far as I can tell, there’s no prop or state change?

Reducers

```
const graphReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
...
        case SHOW_NEXTFOUR:
        console.log('SHOW NEXT FOUR', state);
            return {
                ...state,
                ttlShown: action.ttlShown
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
...
        default:
            return {...state, dontUpdate: true};
    }
};
```

Layout Component

```
class Layout extends Component {
    ...
    handleSideBarOpen = () => {

        this.props.onSidebarToggle();
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Toolbar
                    isAuth={this.props.isAuthenticated}
                    drawerToggleClicked={this.handleSideBarOpen}
                />
                <SideDrawer
                    open={this.props.sidebarOpen}
                    closed={this.props.onSidebarToggle} 

                />
                <main className={classes.Content}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </main>
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ navigation, auth }) => {
    const { sidebarOpen } = navigation;
    const { token } = auth;
    return {
        sidebarOpen,
        isAuthenticated: token !== null 
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    onSidebarToggle, getNavTree
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(Layout);
```

Sidedrawer Component

```
class sideDrawer extends Component {
    state = {
        popupMenuOpen: false
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate ( nextProps, nextState ) {
        if(nextProps.dontUpdate)
            return false;
        else return true;
    }
…

    render() {
        …
        let navitems = [];

        if(this.props.navData && !this.props.error) {
            navitems = (
                <NavigationItems
                    showClients={this.props.showClientsBtn}
                    navData={this.props.navData}
                    curClientid={this.props.curClientid}
                    curSiteid={this.props.curSiteid}
                    curDashid={this.props.curDashid}
                    curPageid={this.props.curPageid}
                    closeSidebar={this.props.closed}
                    onPageClick={this.handlePageClick}
                    onCSDClick={this.handleOpenPopupMenu}
                />
            );
        } else 
            navitems = <p>Problem Loading Tree</p>;

        return (
            <Aux>
                <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')}>
                    <div className={classes.Logo}>
                        <div className={classes.CloseWrapper}>
                            <Chip onClick={this.props.closed} className={classes.CloseChip}>X</Chip>
                        </div>

                        <div className={classes.CrumbWrapper}>
                        <Breadcrumbs 
                            backBtn={this.handleBackClick}
                            handleCrumbClick={this.handleCrumbClick}
                            breadcrumbs={this.props.breadcrumbs}
                        />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <nav>
                        {navitems}
                        <Popover
                        style={{width: "90%"}}
                          open={this.state.popupMenuOpen}
                          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                          anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'middle', vertical: 'bottom'}}
                          targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'middle', vertical: 'top'}}
                          onRequestClose={this.handleClosePopupMenu}
                        >
                          <Menu 
                            style={{width: "87%"}}>
                            {MIs}
                          </Menu>
                        </Popover>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { dontUpdate, clientid, breadcrumbs,currentPage, selectedClient, selectedSite, selectedDash, selectedPage, navigationData, sidebarOpen, navError } = navigation;

    ...

    }
    return {
        dontUpdate,
        clientid,
        showClientsBtn,
        navData,
        curClientid, 
        curSiteid, 
        curDashid, 
        curPageid,
        parentPageid,
        sidebarOpen,
        navError,
        breadcrumbs,
        currentPage
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getNavTree,
    onPageSelected,
    onSwitchCSD,
    onPageRoute
};

export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(sideDrawer));
```

Page Component

```
class Page extends Component {
    componentWillMount () {
        this.props.getCurPage();
    }
    render () {
        let content = null;
        if(this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.currentPage)
            content = (<GraphContainer pageid={this.props.location.state.currentPage} />);

        return this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.currentPage ? (
            <Aux>
                <p>A PAGE!</p>
                {content}
            </Aux>
        ) : (<Redirect to="/" />);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({pages}) => {
    const { clientid, curPage } = pages;
    return {
        clientid, curPage
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getSelectedPage, getCurPage
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(Page);
```

Graph Container

```
class GraphsContainer extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if(this.props.pageid !== newProps.pageid)
            this.props.getFirstEight(newProps.pageid);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.pageid)
            this.props.getFirstEight(this.props.pageid);
    }
    handleNextClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();   
        this.props.getNextEight(this.props.pageid, this.props.lastNum, this.props.ttlShown);
    }
    render() {
        let graphcards = null;
        let disableNext = null;

        if (this.props.lastNum >= this.props.ttl)
            disableNext = true;

        if(this.props.graphs && this.props.graphs.length > 0) {
            graphcards = ...
        }
        return (
            <div className={classes.Shell}>
                {graphcards}
                {this.props.lastNum < this.props.ttl ? (
                    <div className={classes.NavBtns}>
                        <RaisedButton disabled={disableNext} onClick={this.handleNextClick}>{'V'}</RaisedButton>    
                    </div>
                ):null}      
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({pageGraphs}) => {
    const { graphs, ttl, lastNum, ttlShown } = pageGraphs;
    return {
        graphs, ttl, lastNum, ttlShown
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getFirstEight, getNextEight
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(GraphsContainer);
```

Actions

```
export const getFirstEight = (pageid) => {
    let str = ...;
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get( str )
        .then( response => {
            let data = {};
            let graphs;
            let ttl;
            let newLastNum = 0;
            if((typeof response.data !== 'undefined') &&  (response.data !== null)) {
                data = {...response.data};
                ttl = data.total;
                if(ttl <= 8) {
                    graphs = [...data.graphs];
                    newLastNum = ttl;
                } else {
                    graphs = [...data.graphs].slice(0,8);
                    newLastNum = 8;
                }
            }
            dispatch({type: GET_FIRSTEIGHT, payload: {ttl,graphs, lastNum:newLastNum}});
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.log('ERROR FETCHING NAV TREE', error);
            dispatch({type: GET_FIRSTEIGHT, payload: {}});
        } );
    };
};
export const getNextEight = (pageid, lastNum, ttlShown) => {
    let str = ...;
    let newLastNum = 0;
    return (dispatch) => {
        if(ttlShown < lastNum) {
            dispatch({type: SHOW_NEXTFOUR, ttlShown: ttlShown+4});
        } else {
            axios.get( str )
            .then( response => {
                // console.log('[RESPONSE]', response);
                let data = {};
                let graphs;
                let ttl;
                if((typeof response.data !== 'undefined') &&  (response.data !== null)) {
                    data = {...response.data};
                    ttl = data.total;
                    if(ttl <= (lastNum+8)) {
                        graphs = [...data.graphs].slice(lastNum);
                        newLastNum = ttl;
                    } else {
                        graphs = [...data.graphs].filter((el,index) => {
                            return (index > (lastNum-1)) && (index < (lastNum+8));
                        });
                        newLastNum = lastNum+8; 
                    }
                }
                dispatch({type: GET_NEXTEIGHT, payload: {ttl,graphs, lastNum:newLastNum, ttlShown: ttlShown+4}});
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.log('ERROR FETCHING NAV TREE', error);
                dispatch({type: GET_NEXTEIGHT, payload: {}});
            } );
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: your mapDispatchToProps looks potentially problematic, what does `getFirstEight, getNextEight` look like?

Comment: I've included the actions

Comment: Even though you are using `thunk` you still need to dispatch the action from the component so that the middleware can see you are returning a function and inject it with dispatch in the action.

Comment: Actually I see you're asking about something else, nvm.